# How can i run file shell in cakephp 3.0 as cron job with server Docker?

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, nginx, cron

I have a issue and need to someone help me.
I'm deploying a application use framwork CakePHP 3.0.
I created shell file in folder src/Shell.
I used server Docker with mysql and fpm and nginx.
My local is Linux Ubuntu 12.04
Now i want to run this file as cron job. But i didn' find any document about that. I hope someone will help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Use Google? https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=ubuntu+12+chron+job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of Docker, in your PC:

1:    `sudo crontab-e`

2: `5 4 * * * docker exec -i YOUR_PHP_CONTAINER /src/YOUR_PATH_PROJECT/bin/cake yourShellFile yourMethod`